# Sci fi novel, WW2 fighter pilot from alternative universe and his disembodied head co-pilot

Tags: story-identification, novel

Maybe ten years ago I read this but I don't think it was a new book. Can't recall the cover. UK.

There's a pilot from alternative Earth where WW2 continued for decades, he's somehow stranded on our world and living like an amnesiac tramp for a lot of years (I think also, due to some mix up, he has a criminal record as a paedophile so is very unpopular whenever he has to interact with authorities).

He speaks in like 1940's British movie accent. At one point he had (different medical path) a female co-pilot who was just a head, a common practice after severe injuries.

This head had its counterpart in our world but whole bodied - I think other travellers from alt universe recognised her as the first one to have the head operation done.

There were various shenanigans that I don't recall much about - I want to say the pilots aircraft appeared in our world at a different date and astonished rescue workers due to a voice coming from a very small space. This was the head and she also spoke in 1940's accent/slang.

I think she and some scientists from our universe then went exploring across various alt universes and interacting with different people's along the way. Maybe to solve a mystery?

Towards the end she is reunited with the much older version of her pilot and I think they can then return to their plane ('plane' - see what I did there?)

Comment: Vaguely related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/167747/31394 and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/171711/31394

Comment: Not anything on [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:World_War_II_alternate_histories) or [this list](https://www.reddit.com/r/books/comments/6c3ou6/a_list_of_alternate_history_novels/)?

Comment: Thanks @ Rand al'Thor.  I've looked at your suggestions and went through both lists (Inc comments on the Reddit list) but my book's not in them

Answer (score 5):

This was found for me over in SFF Chronicles, the book is *British Summer Time* by Paul Cornell.

Not very much online about it but I did get a blurb as follows ..
.

> Alison Parmeter can read anything—body language, expressions, the shape of a city. Squadron Leader Leyton is a pilot from a utopian future.
>
> He’s dropped back in time, but it’s startlingly different from anything he learned in history lessons.
>
> Jocelyn, his navigator, is a head without a body, captive in a world she can’t trust.
>
> This group must map out a quest for Alison's best friend, who was stolen by the Golden Men, who some call Angels. This quest reaches back to the New Testament, and forward to the end of time.